# How to synchronise the git repository using git hub?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have started using git recently. So, this is what I have done - create a git repository in git hub. I had a project so I pushed my project in the github by the following command -

MACHINE 1 (Ubuntu) - PLACE 1

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/joshis1/XPlatformCoreDumpAnalyzer.git
git push -u origin master
```

MACHINE 2(OSX) PLACE 2

Next, I checked out this code in another machine and network - using git clone.

Next, I did on MACHINE 2, PLACE 2

I created a branch GUI_COMPRESSION_OPTION_FIX and I can see this branch in the github - https://github.com/joshis1/XPlatformCoreDumpAnalyzer/branches

---

Problem - MACHINE 1 PLACE 1

when I do a

```
git pull  https://github.com/joshis1/XPlatformCoreDumpAnalyzer.git
```

Also, when I do gitk, it doesn't show me the branch name - GUI_COMPRESSION_OPTION_FIX.

Looks like, my local git repository is not getting synchronized. My question is how can I force to re-synchronize so that I see the new branch name. I have tried rebase also.

Answer (score 1):

You have it (or at least I got it when I cloned your repo):

```
git clone https://github.com/joshis1/XPlatformCoreDumpAnalyzer.git
Cloning into 'XPlatformCoreDumpAnalyzer'...
remote: Counting objects: 18, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 18 (delta 5), reused 18 (delta 5), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Just do a "git branch --all" and you will find the remote tracking branch there. When you fetch/pull, you automatically get the remote branches in your local repo:

```
~/test/XPlatformCoreDumpAnalyzer (master)$ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/GUI_COMPRESSION_OPTION_FIX
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

"git branch -avv" shows mapping of local branches to remote tracking branches as well:

```
git branch -avv
* master                                    3bd3020 [origin/master] Initial Version - Created the GUI framework for the coredump utility.
  remotes/origin/GUI_COMPRESSION_OPTION_FIX 92465c1 Fixed GUI - compression Type Fix and Logo Fix attempt.
  remotes/origin/HEAD                       -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master                     3bd3020 Initial Version - Created the GUI framework for the coredump utility.
```

Checkout the remote tracking branch to create a local branch `git checkout GUI_COMPRESSION_OPTION_FIX` (that is linked to the remote tracking branch) and now you'll see it as a local branch as well:

```
git branch -avv
* GUI_COMPRESSION_OPTION_FIX                92465c1 [origin/GUI_COMPRESSION_OPTION_FIX] Fixed GUI - compression Type Fix and Logo Fix attempt.
  master                                    3bd3020 [origin/master] Initial Version - Created the GUI framework for the coredump utility.
  remotes/origin/GUI_COMPRESSION_OPTION_FIX 92465c1 Fixed GUI - compression Type Fix and Logo Fix attempt.
  remotes/origin/HEAD                       -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master                     3bd3020 Initial Version - Created the GUI framework for the coredump utility.
```

Comment: Yes, it works when I do a fresh checkout using clone. however, it doesn't work when I am synchronizing on the existing sandbox. I did git checkout remotes/origin/GUI_COMPRESSION_OPTION_FIX